# No module named objc

Tags: python, xcode, pyobjc

I'm trying to use cocoa-python with Xcode but it always calls up the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import objc
ImportError: No module named objc
```

This seems to be because dispite all my attempts to install or find objc and the other modules used by that file, they are simply not on my computer that I can tell, so does anyone know where I can download the actual files (or could put up their own copies?) as in objc.py, Foundation.py, AppKit.py and PyObjCTools.py?

Answer (score 12):

In MacOSX put on console:

`pip install -U pyobjc`

Answer (score 2):

http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/ is the homepage of the whole PyObjC project, so if for some reason it isn't installed along OS X, you can always download it from there.

Comment: I've downloaded that, the .py files aern't in it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Python installation distributed along OS X? For me, /usr/bin/python2.5 finds and can use PyObjC but manually-installed Python 2.6 cannot. I don't know if you can tinker the 2.5 module to work with 2.6.

Comment: It's possible it's not the mac distribution, and it's also 2.7 O_o I tried to get 2.5, but I can't find one with an proper installer

Comment: Python 2.5 should be installed by default in OS X (Leopard and above, I think?), otherwise it might be an even older version. Try opening a shell and tab-completing python and see what you get.

Comment: Typing python into the terminal still works, but I don't have a Macpython 2.5 folder in applications, is it possible for someone to just post a download link for their copies of the modules?

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have multiple Python installations and a misconfigured pythonpath. For more info on one possible way to resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73459838/11072418