# Error when running pyttsx3 in Python 3.9.4 64 bit

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I'm trying to run the following code, but I cannot get it to work even after re-installing pyttsx, installing the pypiwin32 dependency, and specifically installing pyttsx==2.71.

Here is the code:

```
# Imports
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

# Voice Recognition
listener = sr.Recognizer()
speaker = pyttsx3.init()

with sr.Microphone() as input_device:
    print("I am ready")
    voice_content = listener.listen(input_device)
    voice_text = listener.recognize_google(voice_content)
    print(voice_text)

speaker.say("Hello")
speaker.runAndWait()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jackmaling/Desktop/Personal/Personal CS/Kitchen Voice Assistant (Soux)/voice_bot_testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    speaker = pyttsx3.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 12, in <module>
    class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 13, in NSSpeechDriver
    @objc.python_method
NameError: name 'objc' is not defined
```

I would appreciate any direction you can offer. Thank you!

Comment: it may need some other C/C++ libraries or programs and it may need to install them manually (because they are not Python's module)

Comment: @furas how would I do this? Is there a resource that could tell me what libraries I'm missing?

Comment: error shows problem with `objc` which probably means `Object-C` (which exists only on Mac). I checked `NameError: name 'objc' is not defined` in `Google` and I found [python - No module named objc - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678186/no-module-named-objc). I don't use Mac so I can't test it.