# unable to import lightblue module python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, import

I keep getting this error after importing `lightblue` module for python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import lightblue
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lightblue/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    from _lightblue import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lightblue/_lightblue.py", line 23, in <module>
    import Foundation
ImportError: No module named Foundation
```

I have a macbook pro 10.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question at [ImportError: No module named Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614648/importerror-no-module-named-foundation)

Re-installing `pyobjc` seemed to fix it too

```
pip uninstall pyobjc
pip install pyobjc
```