# pyttsx error (mac): cannot find module named foundation

Tags: python

This is my debut in programming, I searched extensively through stakoverflow in order to get an answer but I am kinda lost on this one.

I am trying to get pyttsx to work on my mac.

When i run the following code on python:

```
import pyttsx3
engine  = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("hello")
engine.runAndWait()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 44, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/philippedulbecco/Documents/Untitled.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine  = pyttsx3.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Foundation import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'
```

Any ideas how to fix this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1616361/504930) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm devius's link helped. I had the exact same issue with pyttsx3 on osx. Installing PyObjC solved the problem for me.

```
pip install -U pyobjc
```

https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html