# PyTouchBar: no module named Foundation

Tags: python, python-3.7, foundation

I installed PyTouchBar using `pip3`
When I tried to import it, however, it gives me this error.

```
$ python3
>>> import PyTouchBar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyTouchBar/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .TouchBar import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyTouchBar/TouchBar.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Foundation import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'
```

On Python 2, `Foundation` works perfectly, by the way.
Could someone tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `pip3 install pyobjc`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614648/importerror-no-module-named-foundation)

Comment: I did that, the installation was successful, but I STILL cannot import foundation.

Comment: Okay, I got it working again with a reinstallation, that's really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem could be one of these:

1. You installed PyTouchBar on python2 instead of python3, in which case you have to use:
   `pip3 install PyTouchBar`
2. You are using a venv and installed from the terminal/command line instead of the venv's terminal
3. `PyTouchBar` uses `foundation` that you have to install separately

Comment: But I already tried it, and I cannot find installers for Foundation.

Comment: Is this the one? https://pypi.org/project/foundation/

Comment: No, I need the one that’s related to objc, not django.

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure, perhaps set a bounty once you get enough reputation?

Comment: I tried to reinstall python, and installed pyobjc again works.

Comment: Good, I think something might have been patched or pip wasn't installed correctly before