# trouble with importing python modules

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import Python packages that I had previously installed but I keep getting this error when trying to import it

```
"ImportError: No module named gdal"
```

In the images attached (in the link :P) you can see that the package python-gdal and python-numpy are installed. I am also attaching the python output.

[image]
[image]

P.S = I am using Ubuntu and running python from the terminal.

Comment: Please consider posting the output of terminal as text inside the question. Do you have `pip` installed? If yes, can you also post the result of `pip list`?

Comment: Please post your outputs as text. Try `Ctrl + Shift + C` to copy from terminal or use middle mouse button.

Comment: Also check generic instructions for troubleshooting Python module importing issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783849/how-to-get-more-diagnostic-output-on-a-no-module-named-xyz-error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538725/cant-import-gdal-in-python might be helpful for you

Comment: Try 
    sudo apt-get install python-gdal
then try again importing.

Answer (score 3):

You have possibly installed a **non-Ubuntu version** of Python - **Anaconda** - yet these packages are installed into the system Python. You should probably remove Anaconda, and/or run the system Python explicitly as `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right !!! :D .. I was running a miniconda version and after un-installing it, the import worked fine .. Thank You !!!