# Import GDAL Python failed

Tags: python, ubuntu, gdal

I'm using linux x64 and install GDAL with easy install

```
sudo easy_install GDAL
```

Checking GDAL :

```
reigin@reigin-K43SA:~/pyton$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26
```

But when i use import :

```
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gdal
```

My python path :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/reigin/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-34.3.2-py2.7.egg']
```

I try :
[can't import gdal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538725/cant-import-gdal-in-python)
and 
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython
but idk how to implement this, cz i'm new in python..

any help thanks alot..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `conda`, so try using the conda installer which will also install the GDAL binaries:

`conda install -c conda-forge gdal`

I believe `easy_install` only installs the python bindings. You also need the correct C++ binaries available.

If you are importing gdal installed with conda you should import gdal like this.
`from osgeo import gdal`