# No module named '_gdal' and gdal

Tags: python, gdal

despite the fact that I have installed gdal, it seems that the package does not exist.

```
import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [4] in <cell line: 1>
    import gdal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
conda list gdal
# packages in environment at ....:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
gdal                      3.6.2            py38h2fd6ed0_1  
libgdal                   3.6.2                hc0e11bb_1**
```

When I try to import osgeo i get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

Apart from the fact that it is not recognized, why gdal in the first case and _gdal in the second one?
I was told that I should load gdal outside anaconda in the HPC of my institution, but gdal via command
module load gdal/3.0.1 # the version 3.0.1. is one of the provided for gcc compilers
is available only for gcc compilers, not for intel compilers.

Thanks,
Dimitris

Comment: I followed a solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538725/cant-import-gdal-in-python?rq=4 to rename a folder. This solved the first issue as now 
import gdal is ok. But the second error remains:
import osgeo 
returns  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue was solved as it is described in the comment. The second issue was caused by the absense of file libpoppler.so.126 in the dir .../conda_env/2609_385_intel/2609_385_intel/lib/libpoppler.so.126

So just placing this file in this dir and it solved.
(the file existed in other conda_env of mine so i just copied it in my working conda environment)

Here is the link for the file if needed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HNGYJX8lYd1vXWclxy1Tr7D7TGsYpgTj/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 1):

The correct import statement is

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

Do not rename any folders after installing from `conda`. If you have renamed anything, you have likely broken your installation.